# Which one doesn't belong?

Tags: word-property, odd-one-out

1 of the 5 two-word combinations shown below does not have the same word property as the other 4. Which one? Why?

Note: The answer has nothing to do with the number of: letters, vowels, consonants or syllables. It has nothing to do with meaning of the words or whether a particular letter/s is present or missing.

> 1  Commercial space
>
> 2  Cancun Mexico
>
> 3  Special vaccine
>
> 4  Focaccia slice
>
> 5  Oceanic places

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The answer is

> Cancun Mexico

because in it

> the letter C is only pronounced one way

Comment: Twice at that .

Answer (score 1):

I was a little torn because

> Three of them are adjective-noun, and one is noun-noun (Focaccia slice is noun noun, but I suppose you could stretch to say that focaccia was sort of adjective-like)... but **Cancun Mexico is name-name, so that must be the answer.**

Also note

> The original question asked about word property. When you say word property, I take that to mean the kind or type of word that it is.

Answer (score 1):

The answer must be 5 because it is the only plural.

Comment: And this shows the problem with "odd one out" questions: there are usually multiple answers which could be "correct".

Comment: I once saw an "odd one out" problem whose answer was the only one of the 5 that couldn't be considered the "odd one out" by some criterion, thereby being the "odd one out"